# Аналогия добавления конкретного элемента из библиотеки в C++

Tags: c++, python-3.x

В `Python` есть возможность добавить в Ваш код конкретный элемент из библиотеки. Для этого используется команда `from`.
Пример
`from Name import Something`
Меня интересует, есть ли аналогия этой команды в `C++`.

Comment: Нет, в С++ тянется сразу все содержимое - `#include <something>`

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, спасибо за ответ

Comment: Что такое "элемент"? В С++ традиционное поведение линкера заключается в том, что из библиотеки берется только те объектные файлы, которые нужны для разрешения неразрешенных ссылок. Это делается автоматически. Однако многие компиляторы поддерживают линковку на уровне отдельных функций. Однако это совсем не то, что в Питоне. В С++ пока нет модулей и библиотеки представляют собой совсем другие по своей сути сущности.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb: `#include` ничего никуда еще не тянет.